# Convert string date to datetime js

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm stucked on javascript.
I get thi example string from JSON :

```
Saturday 14th August
```

How can i convert it in

```
 14/08/2021
```

Thanks.

Comment: how do you get the year from the string ?

Comment: @svarog common practice is getting the current year if the year is not specified.

Comment: than how do you avoid accidently getting dates in the future ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Pure Javascript` with much more logic. My suggestion is to use [**Moment.Js**](https://momentjs.com/) It's a really easy way to handle complex **DateTime** data.

***Check this working code:***

```js
const dateString = "Saturday 14th August";
const formattedDate = moment(dateString, "dddd Do MMMM").format("DD/MM/Y");

console.log(formattedDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**NOTE:**

As `@svarog` mentioned in the comment, It's hard to find the year, If it's not provided. But the common practice is getting the current year. **Moment JS** handles this very well.

Comment: MomentJS is unmaintained library as of 2021

Comment: @GaëlJ—moment.js isn't unmaintained, it's considered "[*a legacy project in maintenance mode*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)". But yes, it's recommended not to use it for new projects. Also, there are many, many very much smaller date libraries that are good alternatives for parsing and formatting, or a simple 3 line function.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let jsonDateString = "Saturday 14th August" 
//this is the string you get 

let jsonDateStringArray = jsonDateString.split(" "); 
//here we split the words so we can better manipulate them

let month = jsonDateStringArray[2]; 
//we save the month here

let day = jsonDateStringArray[1].replace(/\D/g, ""); 
//saving the day and removing everything but numbers

let year = new Date().getFullYear(); 
//creating a date so we can get the year without having to hardcode it


let completeDate = new Date(Date.parse(month + ' ' + day + ', ' + year));
//create a new date from the string we pass 'August 14, 2021'


console.log(completeDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB'));
//parameter en-GB for 14/08/21, without parameter we get 08/14/2021
```

Comment: `new Date(Date.parse(month + ' ' + day + ', ' + year))` is not a good idea, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)